# installing GD and gd module

Tags: python

I am having trouble installing the gd library and `gdmodule` for python firstly I have done

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
sudo apt-get install libgd2-xpm-dev
```

then trying to install the gd module using `sudo python Setup.py install` which I downloaded from http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/gdmodule.html

I get the warning WARNING: missing gd, jpeg, png, gif, z, x11, Xmp, rtf, freetype Libraries Can't Find GD Libraries

How can I install both properly, I get no errors when installing the first two. I am completely stuck and I am very new to using Ubuntu, so do not know a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to install gd from source, it's in the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gd
```

If, for some reason, you still want to install from source, it's easy to install all build dependencies as well:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-gd
```

Comment: I still get the warning error for the gd module part though

Comment: and when I try to install from the source it says `unable to find source package for python-gd`